# Ember.js removes and adds the same CSS class for bindAttr

Tags: ember.js

Given

```
<div {{bindAttr class="test"}}>
```

When the computed property test is updated but its value stays the same, the test CSS class is removed and added. This creates a problem when the class has CSS animations, as re adding the class restarts the animation. Is there a way to not remove and add the class if it's already part of the element?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? How is your computed property defined? You can use this as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/eTcDu/

Answer (score 0):

Ember observers are fired whenever a value is set, not just when the value is changed.  A possible solution to your problem is to introduce a 2nd property which is set only when the value actually changes.  Something like:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="stableTest"}}>
```

And then in something like a view:

```
onTestChanged: function() {
    var test = this.get('test');
    var stableTest = this.get('stableTest');
    if (test !== stableTest) {
        this.set('stableTest', test);
    }
}.observes('test')
```